# MySQL JSON_OBJECT does not retain order of values?

Tags: sql, json, mysql-5.7

I have the following query to return a json object. I want the json object of the `formatted_criteria` to return the values as per the order I have defined in the query i.e `Location` first and `Radius` second.

However the returned results are simply maintaining the order of the original 
`criteria` column.

```
 select a.id
      , a.name
      , a.criteria
      , JSON_OBJECT(
         'Location', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria, '$.location')),
         'Radius', CONCAT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria, '$.radius')), ' miles')
        ) as formatted_criteria
 from alerts as a
```

Results:

```
id |   name   |               criteria                      |        formatted_criteria 
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9 |   test   | {"radius": "30", "location": "Manchester"}  | {"Radius": "30 miles", "Location": "Manchester"}
```

As you can see the formatted_criteria has re-ordered the values?

How can I get it to return the results in the order that I want.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question was asked a long time ago but I have come across this scenario many a time myself.  The only way that I've found to order resulting JSON objects using JSON_OBJECT is quite simply: *not to use it*.  I simply construct the desired JSON using CONCAT, GROUP_CONCAT and the required quotes/separators to achieve the desired results.

The one-time effort (per scenario) it takes to do this is commensurate with the value you see in having the key/pairs ordered in the fashion you require.  If it's not that important, the JSON_OBJECT produces valid json as standard json does not in any way recognize ordering of elements.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A method I use to order the result is adding whitespace to the key. The result is ordered from shortest to longest key.

```
JSON_OBJECT(
     'Location', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria, '$.location')),
     'Radius   ', CONCAT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.criteria, '$.radius')), ' miles')
    )
```